# How to remove file from git repository like it never existed

Tags: git, delete-file

I am trying to delete some big file (512MB) from my repo. As I noticed `git rm bigfile` removes file only from recent commint.

So I found some command: `git filter-branch --index-filter 'rm -f bigfile' -- --all`. And it succefully deleted file from all commits.

But repo still has big size `du -hs .` reports 512MB. There is some file in `.git/objects/pack/pack-a8e5a5ed17f31ed45ea7f387245265206e4f4c39.pack` which has 512MB. Is it safe to delete it manually or is there some git command how to clear it?

Comment: Because git retains objects for a while unless they get expired after a certain amount of time. Inspect your local refs first by using `git show-ref`, then delete unnecessary ones if any (be careful) by using `git update-ref -d`, and then collect git repository garbage by using `git clear` (if you don't care about the reflog).

Comment: Command `git show-ref` shows only:  `a2c2fb06ef3e81f19f3243a3e804e123db7d52f2 refs/heads/master`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43640996/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+compress

Comment: Thanks, so this worked: 
```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch bigfile" -- --all
rm -rf .git/refs/original/
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```